# Removing neatline in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, layouts

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1. I accidentally added a neatline, but now I can't remove it. I now have an ugly white space in between my map and the neatline.

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you chose to make it part of an element or set of elements, then it gets created as the frame of the element/s. You can go into the properties of the element/s and change the border, background and/or shadow to none as needed.

Answer (score 0):

From view menu choose dataframe properties then choose frame subtitle. Then, select ***no color*** for border.